# Facebook Dialog Tutorial - Is Something Missing?

Tags: android, callback

This is code from the following page: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#setup

I'm trying to get this to work but am extremely confused with the "callback" argument when instantiating the UILifecycleHelper class. (Looking at the tutorial code) I dont see where this variable is coming from. Ive attempted to create a null object and pass it, but (surprise) got a NullPointerException.

Has Facebook forgot a step here or is it there some impicit knowledge from which my lack of understanding Callbacks are coming back to haunt me?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);    // line 45 in code
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Thank you for your assistance

// EDIT (Again) - wrong trace

Here's the stack trace - there's a lot of ECLIPSE errors to wade through as well (cant figure how to get rid of them all), so just ignore those:

```
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.theperspectableone.carddisplayertemplate/com.theperspectableone.carddisplayertemplate.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:227)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:212)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(UiLifecycleHelper.java:87)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.theperspectableone.carddisplayertemplate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-16 19:24:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You should implement that callback on the fly, I think that is the problem, but I'm not sure until I see the stack trace.

Comment: ok.. ive added the logcat errs

Comment: lame me - had wrong trace. This is the correct one.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ Maybe you forgot to insert your appid into the manifest.xml ?

Comment: @idipaolo - well, im not trying to make a Facebook app, but rather a simple Facebook dialog... maybe thats the prob. *hands in the air*

Comment: I think you can't do that without creating a simple facebook app, it's also written in the doc here `To get started using the native Share Dialog, follow the instructions in Getting Started for installing the SDK and adding it your app.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is ion what Idipaolo said.... you have to follow the setup instructions as well as the share dialog.

You end up needing to create a Developer Account with Facebook, which also entails the following:

```
Having "keytool" in your computer ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
Installing and having "openssl" in your computer ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
Creating a keystore
Creating a Key
Creating a new App on the Facebook Developer page
Putting the Key in the app info page
Getting an App ID from Facebook
A plethora of other setup things in your Android file
```

This site helped me with getting the key (although the actual FB code is deprecated): http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

This got the Dialog up and running (although there is one line which is deprecated and still causing me grief*): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#setup

```
*Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
```

Comment: btw.... the new facebook sdk 3.6 makes this irrelevant. I found that by updating these problems went away as new code (and new way of implementing it) was introduced.